# Python method arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I use some frameworks and create methods in class, pass them arguments which has default values.

And values are inknown for me. I don't know how to create methods like this?

I know how default argument works, but for example:

```
def paint(self, e):
    print e # this is wx python and e is class object which i haven't passed.
```

Comment: I don't think your confusion is how it is defined, but how it is called. It looks like a method that is typically called by other parts of the framework, rather than by you. The framework is responsible for passing the correct argument in that case.

Comment: You'll find [Default Argument Values](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values) at a very early point in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

To set a default values for a method you do this:

```
def myFunction(parameter1, defaultParameter = None):
    #your code
```